# How to optimise a table for AVG query?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I have a table that looks like this:

```
| calls | CREATE TABLE `calls` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `request_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `ct` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `wt` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `cpu` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `mu` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `pmu` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `caller_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `callee_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `caller_id` (`caller_id`,`request_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3164057 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
```

and a query that is simply:

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT
    -> AVG(`c1`.`wt`) `wt`,
    -> AVG(`c1`.`cpu`) `cpu`,
    -> AVG(`c1`.`mu`) `mu`,
    -> AVG(`c1`.`pmu`) `pmu`
    -> FROM
    -> `calls` `c1`;
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | c1    | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 3161147 |       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT
    -> AVG(`c1`.`wt`) `wt`,
    -> AVG(`c1`.`cpu`) `cpu`,
    -> AVG(`c1`.`mu`) `mu`,
    -> AVG(`c1`.`pmu`) `pmu`
    -> FROM
    -> `calls` `c1`;
+-----------+----------+------------+------------+
| wt        | cpu      | mu         | pmu        |
+-----------+----------+------------+------------+
| 2285.2079 | 428.2061 | 30567.4517 | 24925.7182 |
+-----------+----------+------------+------------+
1 row in set (1.61 sec)
```

The server is pretty fast (24 GB of RAM). The most relevant of the `my.cnf` ([full my.cnf](https://gist.github.com/bfab4e034df75bb0c46f)) is:

```
query_cache_type=0
query_cache_size=0
key_buffer_size=50M
sort_buffer_size=10M
innodb_buffer_pool_size=1G
read_rnd_buffer_size=1M
join_buffer_size=4M
max_connections=400
table_cache=2000
table_definition_cache=2000
```

Is there anything I can do to optimise the query? With only 5,278,808 records, it seems unlikely that I've reached the hardware limits.

I've also tried moving the entire table to a otherwise the same `ENGINE=MEMORY` table. The time improved by roughly 30%. However, that's still slow.

Comment: is it posible to have a "live sum" on a single record on other table and maintain it acurate with an update/delete/insert tirgger on 'calls' table???

Comment: could you solve your problem?  or did you find a workaround? please share here ;)

Comment: @LuisSiquot, I didn't actually solve the problem. My workaround will not be useful to the majority of the audience. However, I ended up using `TEMPORARY` tables with `ENGINE=MEMORY`. My main problem wasn't that the query takes 300ms (or whatever else large the number would be), but that I had to issue this query 5 or more times every script run ordering/grouping the data in different ways. Aggregating the dataset of interest into a temporary memory table helped me to cut the page loading time 80%+.

Answer (score 0):

The best short therm thing you can do is to add an index that will cover 4 fields you calculating.
Right now you doing a full table scan, operation that going over all pages that contain your table if you make an index covering just 4 columns above MySQL will go over index instead , index stored separately and contains less data so more data will fit in a single page.

Comment: I don't think so, this is not a mater of I/O, the issue here is to sum up so much data. please avoid 'see my updated anwser' as OP is notified anyway

Comment: Well, out of curiosity I've created a new table that contains only the relevant columns – the difference (if any) is insignificant.

Comment: How can you determine that is not an I/O issue ? You don't have enough information to know this. Also you can try to compute avg of 5m number in your favorite language you will see that it will be crazy fast.

Comment: @MichaelT What if my favourite language is PHP? :-) Anyway, that's off-topic.

Comment: @Guy you should increase your innodb_buffer_pool_size to 80% of your available memory right now you using just a fraction of available memory, also try to measure your queries, and yes even PHP will be fast in this task

Comment: `innodb_buffer_pool_size` further increasing is irrelevant because even the present storage is not fully utilised.

Comment: Only if you a single user of this DB and running a single query.

Comment: @MichaelT, see the updated question. (I am not sure if you are notified about the changes to the question;)

Answer (score 0):

You could try and avoid looking at old data over and over again...

Maybe store the record counts and summed values in another table along with the datetime last updated and add a datetime column to your calls table (make sure it is indexed).

When you need to calculate the averages, just look at data created after the last time you checked, combine this with the data in the new table, and update the new table.

It would get more complicated if your old data can be updated - you would probably need to have triggers then.